# Select an image form upload table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a form which allows me to create an insert into a table called `client`, along with that theres an upload field which uploads an image into an uploads folder and then uploads the path into the db along with the client ID. I am wanting to then select and show the rows from the client table along with the image that is associated to it in the uploads table. My select statement is very simple:

```
        <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client ORDER BY client_name ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>

            <?php echo '<li class="client_list">' ?>
                <?php //client image to show here from uploads table ?>
                <?php echo $row["client_name"]; ?>
            <?php echo '</li>' ?>   

        <?php   }
        } else{
            echo "There are no tasks!";
        }
        ?>
```

But I am not sure on how to approach getting the image path form the uploads table which has the client id in the the same table.

Comment: use a WHERE clause and get the path/image row, then echo accordingly

Comment: but would a WHERE clause be ok to get data form another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a table named "client" and another table named "upload", you should first query your data like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT client_name, image_path FROM client JOIN
upload ON client.id = upload.client_id ORDER BY client_name ASC";
```

and then include the image as proposed before:

```
<?php echo '<img src="',$row["image_path"],'"/>'; ?>
```

Comment: Ok that seems to be a success! I see what you have done here to make this work.